# Como puedo automatixar el proceso de cambiar el JDK

Tags: java, windows10

Tengo varias versiones de java instaladas, un JDK para Java 8, un JDK para Java 11, y dos JDK para Java 13.

## ¿Qué he intentado?

De momento lo que he hecho es agregar más variables de sistema como por ejemplo `JAVAOCHO_ORACLE` O `OPENJNUEVE`.

E ir apuntando a ellas con mi variable `JAVA_HOME`.

```
@echo off 
set "JAVA5_FOLDER=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_22"
set "JAVA6_FOLDER=C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45"
set "JAVA7_FOLDER=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80"
set "JAVA8_FOLDER=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"
set "JAVA9_FOLDER=C:\Java\jdk-10.0.1"
set "CLEAR_FOLDER=C:\xxxxxx"

(echo "%PATH%" & echo.) | findstr /O . | more +1 | (set /P RESULT= & call exit /B %%RESULT%%)
set /A STRLENGTH=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo path length = %STRLENGTH%
if %STRLENGTH% GTR 1024  goto byebye 

echo Old Path: %PATH%
echo =================== 
echo Choose new Java Version:
echo [5] JDK5
echo [6] JDK6 
echo [7] JDK7
echo [8] JDK8
echo [9] JDK10
echo [x] Exit

:choice 
SET /P C=[5,6,7,8,9,x]? 
for %%? in (5) do if /I "%C%"=="%%?" goto JDK_L5 
for %%? in (6) do if /I "%C%"=="%%?" goto JDK_L6
for %%? in (7) do if /I "%C%"=="%%?" goto JDK_L7 
for %%? in (8) do if /I "%C%"=="%%?" goto JDK_L8 
for %%? in (9) do if /I "%C%"=="%%?" goto JDK_L9
for %%? in (x) do if /I "%C%"=="%%?" goto byebye
goto choice 

@echo on
:JDK_L5  
set "NEW_PATH=%JAVA5_FOLDER%"
goto setPath

:JDK_L6  
@echo off 
set "NEW_PATH=%JAVA6_FOLDER%"
goto setPath

:JDK_L7  
@echo off 
set "NEW_PATH=%JAVA7_FOLDER%"
goto setPath

:JDK_L8  
@echo off 
set "NEW_PATH=%JAVA8_FOLDER%"
goto setPath

:JDK_L9  
@echo off 
set NEW_PATH = %JAVA9_FOLDER%

:setPath
Call Set "PATH=%%PATH:%JAVA5_FOLDER%=%CLEAR_FOLDER%%%"
Call Set "PATH=%%PATH:%JAVA6_FOLDER%=%CLEAR_FOLDER%%%"
Call Set "PATH=%%PATH:%JAVA7_FOLDER%=%CLEAR_FOLDER%%%"
Call Set "PATH=%%PATH:%JAVA8_FOLDER%=%CLEAR_FOLDER%%%"
Call Set "PATH=%%PATH:%JAVA9_FOLDER%=%CLEAR_FOLDER%%%"
rem echo Interim Path: %PATH%
Call Set "PATH=%%PATH:%CLEAR_FOLDER%=%NEW_PATH%%%" 

setx PATH "%PATH%" /M

call set "JAVA_HOME=%NEW_PATH%"
setx JAVA_HOME %JAVA_HOME% 

echo New Path: %PATH%
:byebye
echo
java -version
pause
```

[Detección de los JDK's instalados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/372612/obtener-las-rutas-de-instalaci%C3%B3n-de-jdk-asumiendo-que-no-est%C3%A1n-en-el-path/372615#372615)

### ¿Qué busco?

Me gustaría usar alguna herramienta o alguna otra solución no tan manual como cambiar a mano el valor de mis variables, algo similar a [nvm](/questions/tagged/nvm) pero para Java.

Comment: Eh, una primera aproximación que se me ocurre es crear powershells y que los ejecutes desde el escritorio (o desde otro shell o desde tus aplicaciones) para manipular tus variables de entorno.

Comment: Aunque tu **pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros, herramientas, librerías u otros recursos externos**, motivo por el cual terminará cerrada, creo que lo que buscas es: [Jabba](https://github.com/shyiko/jabba). Saludos

Comment: @Alfabravo sí, pensé lo mismo, pero no creo ser el primero que se le ocurre. según recuerdo se podía con jenv, pero no tengo suficiente experiencia y es lo que me gustaría ver en las respuestas, pros y contras y su compatibilidad con windows 10, y pues si no hay nada chido o que se siga manteniendo para programar algo yo mismo.

Comment: @MauricioContreras no es necesario que sea una herramienta, la idea es automatizar una tarea trivial

Answer (score 3):

## Opción 1

**coursier**
https://get-coursier.io/
Escrita en Scala, multiplatforma

Instalación (en Linux y similarmente en Windows):

```
$ curl -fLo cs https://git.io/coursier-cli-linux && chmod +x cs && ./cs
```

Descubrir `JAVA_HOME` actual:

```
$ coursier java-home
/usr/lib/jvm/java-14
```

Enumerar las versiónes conocidas y desponibles de OpenJDK:

```
$  coursier java --available | grep adopt
adopt:1.8.0-172
adopt:1.8.0-181
```

Descargar y generar las variables de entorno para OpenJDK 14:

```
* coursier java --jvm 14 --env
Extracting
  /home/user/.cache/coursier/v1/https/github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk14-binaries/releases/download/jdk-14.0.1%252B7/OpenJDK14U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_14.0.1_7.tar.gz
in
  /home/user/.cache/coursier/jvm/adopt@1.14.0-1
Done
export CS_FORMER_JAVA_HOME="$JAVA_HOME"
export JAVA_HOME="/home/user/.cache/coursier/jvm/adopt@1.14.0-1"
export PATH="/home/user/.cache/coursier/jvm/adopt@1.14.0-1/bin:$PATH"
```

Cambiar entros las versiónes de JDK:

```
$ eval "$(cs java --jvm 11 --env)"
$ eval "$(cs java --jvm 13 --env)"
$ eval "$(cs java --disable)" # volvel a la configuración original
```

## Opción 2

**SDKman**
https://sdkman.io/
Multiplatforma, pero es necesario tener WSL o Cygwin

Instalación (en Linux o WSL):

```
$curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Enumerar las versiónes conocidas y desponibles de JDK:

```
$ sdk list java
```

Descargar y instalar una versión de JDK:

```
$ sdk install java 11.0.7.hs-adpt
Downloading: java 11.0.7.hs-adpt
In progress...
Done installing!
Setting java 11.0.7.hs-adpt as default.
'/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/java/current' -> '/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.7.hs-adpt'
$ which java
/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java
```

## Opción 3

**jEnv**
https://www.jenv.be/
Sólo UNIXes (Linux y Mac OS) y no puede descargar de Internet

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jenv/jenv.git ~/.jenv
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Añadir JDKs existentes:

```
$ jenv add /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0
$ jenv add /usr/lib/jvm/java-14
$ jenv versions
* system 
  openjdk64-14.0.1
  openjdk64-1.8.0.252
```

Cambiar a la versión especifica:

```
$ jenv global openjdk64-14.0.1
```