# Obtener las rutas de instalación de JDK asumiendo que no están en el PATH

Tags: cmd, windows10

Quisiera detectar todas las instalaciones que tengo en mi máquina de el JDK de Java y obtener sus rutas de instalación.

De momento llevo la primera parte mediante:

```
C:\Users\RuslanLopez>wmic product where "Name like '%%JDK%%'" get name,version
```

Esto me da mis programas instalados que tengan la palabra JDK en ellos, pero no sabría en que directorio están instalados.

> Name                                                 Version
>
> AdoptOpenJDK JDK with Eclipse OpenJ9 13.0.1.9 (x64)  13.0.1.9
>
> AdoptOpenJDK JDK with Hotspot 8.0.242.08 (x64)       8.0.242.08

Las rutas en este caso no son las mismas que las de Oracle, así que me gustaría no asumir que están donde siempre, existe algo extra que le pueda pedir al comando WMIC para saber que archivos se instlaron en que rutas para eso producto o algo similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afortunadamente hallé que se puede mejorar el query para obtener la ruta de instalación agregando `InstallLocation`, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
wmic product where "Name like '%%JDK%%'" get name,version,InstallLocation
```

> InstallLocation                                        Name            Version
>
> C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-13.0.1.9-openj9\     AdoptOpenJDK
> JDK with Eclipse OpenJ9 13.0.1.9 (x64)  13.0.1.9
>
> C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.242.08-hotspot\  AdoptOpenJDK
> JDK with Hotspot 8.0.242.08 (x64)       8.0.242.08

Answer (score 0):

Algo que podría servirte es por ejemplo descargar el *Subsystem* de Linux para Windows y buscarlo con comandos las rutas solo escribiendo `whereis java` para que te muestre las rutas absolutas donde hay instalaciones de java como el `JDK` en tu caso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Referencia: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: En windows existe el comando where, pero no haya las cosas si no están en el PATH, al tener dos instalaciones, por lo menos una no está en el PATH.

Comment: ahhh adicionalmente no sirve whereis java, sino whereis javac ya que se trata de hallar JDKs y no runtimes

Answer (score 0):

En Linux puedes usar el siguiente comando:

```
dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java)))
```

Comment: esto es incorrecto porque como verás es para windows

Comment: Entiendo, pero el título es muy general, en mi caso cuando necesitaba me salió esta pregunta, pero no fue de ayuda, por lo tanto, agrego la respuesta en caso de alguien lo necesite.